# fputs GET to curl

Tags: php, curl, fgets, fputs

I have this script which requires `allow_url_fopen = On` which is not a good idea and I want to change `curl`.  I'll appreciate if any one can help me out with how to do the `fputs GET`.

```
$SH = fsockopen($IP, $Port, $errno, $errstr, 30);
echo $errstr;    
#$ch = curl_init();
#curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 30);
#curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $IP.":".$Port);
#curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
    if ($SH){ 
        fputs($SH,"GET /7.html HTTP/1.0\r\nUser-Agent: S_Status (Mozilla Compatible)\r\n\r\n");
        $content = "";
        while(!feof($SH)) { 
            $content .= fgets($SH, 1000);
            #content .= curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FILE, $SH);
        }
        fclose($SH);
        #curl_close($ch);
}
```

Comment: Can you declare a concrete question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you're just looking for how to send the HTTP request (that's what your `fputs($SH, "GET ...")` is doing, that is done using `curl_exec()`. Seems like this should work.

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 30);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PORT, $Port);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $IP . '/7.html');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'S_Status (Mozilla Compatible)'); 
//tell curl to return the output, not display it
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true); 
//execute the request
$content = curl_exec($ch);
```